# How do I reset all options() arguments to their default values?

Tags: r, settings

As noted in the title, I'm trying to understand how to reset all arguments in `options()` to their default settings.  I searched online and in the `?options` help file and am failing to locate an answer.

I expect the answer is readily available, and I'm simply struggling to find it.

Thanks.

*Edit:*  While I agree [How to set R to default options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946953/how-to-set-r-to-default-options) is the same question, I'm failing to see in its selected answer the clear/explicit solution I requested: how to **reset** `options()` to its defaults.  The selected answer in that thread clearly explains how to *save* `options()` settings and *load* them later.

Comment: I agree this question is the same as [How to set R to default options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946953/how-to-set-r-to-default-options)  The issue I have with that thread is I feel the _selected_ answer, there, is different than what I would select for my purposes (namely, one that outlines how to reset `options()` to R's default, rather than save and reload my own `options()` settings).

Comment: The answer in the linked question provides the necessary information. If you open a separate R session, it will start with the default option settings. You can save these default settings in a file and load that file into the other session in order to restore the default values.

Comment: As I noted in another comment below, I'm presently failing to see in the answer from the other thread that opening a new session will start with default option settings.  (I do see its discussion about saving settings and then restoring them, later.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you restart your R session, it will reset the options to the default values. 
Options are saved in a list, and calling `options()` will show that list.

You can save the default options after restarting R:

`backup_options <- options()`

You can make any changes you need, and then to revert to the default options:

`options(backup_options)`

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  I would prefer something that's possible in-session; however, since I'm failing to locate an in-session solution and opening a new R session does work for me, I selected this as the answer.  NOTE:  I've also found saving my workspace does not change this functionality (I thought opening R from a saved workspace might result in customized, rather than default, options -- it opens with the defaults).

Comment: This will *not* delete any options that you set and that are not part of `backup_options`, right?

Answer (score 7):

#### Simply run this:

```
default_opts <- callr::r(function(){options()}); options(default_opts)
```

#### How it works

It works by starting a separate background process, accessing the default options within that session, and supplying the options back to the current session.

#### Example

```
# Default option
options("scipen")
# $scipen
# [1] 0

# Set to something else
options(scipen = 999)
# $scipen
# [1] 999

# Reset to defaults:
default_opts <- callr::r(function(){options()}); options(default_opts)

# Option is back to its default value
options("scipen")
# $scipen
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 4):

I never tried it myself, but the [`settings`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/settings/index.html) package seems to provide a possibility to restore the default values without previously storing them:

```
library(settings)
reset(options)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  This failed to work for me.  After installing and opening the `settings` package, I tested `reset(options)` by first using `options(warn = 2)`.  When I ran `options("warn")` the result was `$warn [1] 2`.  I understand per `?options` the default for `warn` is 0.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work. As I said, I didn't test it. The description of the package seemed to fit to your question. It may be necessary to delve deeper into the package manual. Or use the solution described in the previous answer in the linked question: Open a new session, store the default options in a file, and load that file in your current session.

Comment: I'm fine, thanks.  Maybe you could edit the answer on the other thread ([How to set R to default options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946953/how-to-set-r-to-default-options)) because I gleaned from that how to _store_ my settings, rather than that opening a new R session would reset `options()` to its default settings.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the answer by @PaulHiemstra . The trick is to open a new R session, which will automatically start with default options. The options of this session (personalized or not) can be stored in a file and read in later in another session to set the options to these values.

Comment: I definitely could be misunderstanding the answer by Paul.  If opening a new R session is implied in his answer, I'm really struggling to see it and suggest someone edit it to make it explicit or at least more pronounced.  :-)