# Setting and resetting scipen and digits in R options with package `settings`

Tags: r, settings

Setting `options` in R can be useful when wanting to avoid scientific notation. `options(scipen = 100, digits = 4)` is one possibility.

It seems that at the start of every R session in R Studio this command needs to be re-run.

I was searching for a way to reset all R `options` once they have been set and found this post: [How do I reset all options() arguments to their default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848785/how-do-i-reset-all-options-arguments-to-their-default-values)

The actual answer comes 'to late' once the `options` have been set already. The package `settings` offers a way to reset all options in R. This does not seem to work for `scipen` and `digits` however (see example).

---

**Example**:

```r
require(settings)
#> Loading required package: settings

1/987654
#> [1] 1.0125e-06

options(scipen = 100, digits = 4)

1/987654
#> [1] 0.000001013

settings::reset(options)

1/987654
#> [1] 0.000001013
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

**Questions**:

1. Is there any other possibility to reset both `scipen` and `digits` to their standard values?
2. What are the standard values?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to solve your problem for now: the defaults are `options(scipen=0, digits=7)`

But generally, I think the way R works is that options are set at startup, and the defaults are not stored anywhere explicitly.
Also, the notion of a "default" may be fuzzy, if you set options in configuration files such as `.Rprofile`.

So I think the most useful way to reset all options is a simple restart.
If you want to keep your data you can use `save.image()`. And mostly, I found that restarting often made my code much more reproducible.