# setting a global format for displaying numbers in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, format

I am working on a `Rmarkdown` document with uses plots and `data.table`. There are a lot of very large values in my data set like `6000000000000`. There are hard to read and i was wondering if there was an option to change the format of these variables?

For now, i have used `labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ", scientific = FALSE)` within the `ggplot`, but that is very tedious and still leaves all ym table unformatted.

Expected output: 
6 000 000 000 000

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882326/setting-and-resetting-scipen-and-digits-in-r-options-with-package-settings

Comment: yes, but not quite what i am after

Comment: If using `6000000000000` as an example, what is your expected output?

Comment: This will depend heavily on how you are printing the numbers in your document. There is  not a universal option. You mention `ggplot`... are there other places this arises? Are you producing table outputs? Directly printing your `data.table` objects? Using inline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `scales` library:

```
scales::number_format()(6000000)
```

Returns

> `[1] "6 000 000"`