# How does really work saving, changing and restoring options using options() and getOption()

Tags: r

Following the sugestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946953/how-to-set-r-to-default-options) from: @Hiemstra (Paul Hiemstra), I am trying to reproduce a similar situation for saving, changing an restoring the options in R, using options(), getOption() functions:

```
print("Print options. Expected null/empty values")
print(paste("[cats.funName, cats.value]=[", getOption("cats.funName"), ",",
    getOption("cats.value"), "]", sep=""))
print("Saving the options...")
system("rm 'default_options.rda'")
default_options = options()
save(default_options, file = "default_options.rda")
print("Verify the rda file was created...")
system("ls 'default_options.rda'")
rm(default_options)
print(ls())
print("Changing the options...")
options("cats.funName" = "my_functionName")
options("cats.value" = sqrt(2))
print(paste("[cats.funName, cats.value]=[", getOption("cats.funName"), ",",
    getOption("cats.value"), "]", sep = ""))
print("Restoring original options...")
print(load("default_options.rda"))
print("variables defined after loading default_options: ls()...")
print(ls())
options(default_options)
print("Printing the options, expected null/empty values...")
print(paste("[cats.funName, cats.value]=[", getOption("cats.funName"), ",",
    getOption("cats.value"), "]", sep = ""))
```

And I get the following output:

```
[1] "Print options. Expected null/empty values"
[1] "[cats.funName, cats.value]=[,]"
[1] "Saving the options..."
[1] "Verify the rda file was created..."
default_options.rda
character(0)
[1] "Changing the options..."
[1] "[cats.funName, cats.value]=[my_functionName,1.4142135623731]"
[1] "Restoring original options..."
[1] "default_options"
[1] "variables defined after loading default_options: ls()..."
[1] "default_options"
[1] "Printing the options, expected null/empty values..."
[1] "[cats.funName, cats.value]=[my_functionName,1.4142135623731]"
>
```

I expected empty values because the cats* properties were not saved previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `options()` with a list will only set those values found in the list. It will not remove values not found in the list. You could find a list of all the options that are set that were not in your list with

```
to_remove <- setdiff(names(options()), names(default_options))
```

and then remove them with

```
options(Map(function(x) NULL, to_remove))
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick it works, so there is no a single function that restores to the previous status of the option variables?

Comment: No, not that I know of. Options are meant to be set or changed, not removed. In theory you might be able to mess directly with `.Options` but that's only there for S compatibility per the documentation so I wouldn't just replace it. But be careful, future version of R may have new options and loading a file that doesn't have those set may cause problems if they are removed.